# How can I execute a Terminal command before running the live CD installer?

Tags: installation, live-cd, command-line

When I run the live CD installer, the installation gets stuck at "select a picture for the specified account." I've found that is an incompatibility problem with my webcam and the only way to fix this is running the Terminal command:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideogp
```

This must be run before doing the installation. But because its a live cd, I don't know exactly how to do that. I've tried opening the terminal normally and executing this command, but I open the setup and still stuck.

How can I run this command in a Terminal on the live CD?

Answer (score 4):

Select the option `Try Ubuntu without installing` from the boot menu when you start up the live CD, instead of the `Install Ubuntu` option. Then you boot into a usable Ubuntu desktop which runs as '[live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_cd).' From the desktop, you can open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command. Then when you're done in the Terminal, start the Install process by double-clicking the `Install Ubuntu` icon on the desktop.

That is the best way to do it. But if you ever need to enter a command after you've already selected `Install Ubuntu` instead of `Try Ubuntu without installing`, then you can run it in a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and you'll get a text-based screen where you can enter commands. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the graphical user interface. Commands that are doing work in the one virtual console (e.g., the 1st one, accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) will continue to run even after you've switched to a different virtual console (or back to the GUI).

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, thanks for adding the second paragraph. but I have one doubt, if we take the virtual console by using Ctrl+Alt+F1- would we get the terminal directly or the screen to input username and password. The issue is whether it would ask for username and password.

Comment: For ubuntu server, there is no 'try ubuntu without installing' item. What should I do now?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde, As far as I know, unfortunately, `Ubuntu Server`, does not have such a facility, allowing commands to be run before installation.